# multiple trackbars in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have used the example code from microsoft to create a task bar, but i am unable to use it to create multiple task bars

Here is the code I'm using

```
public class form1
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();

        // TextBox for TrackBar.Value update.
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(240, 0);
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 20);

        // Set up how the form should be displayed and add the controls to the form.
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(296, 62);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[]
        {
            this.textBox1, this.trackBar1
        });
        this.Text = "TrackBar Example";

        // Set up the TrackBar.
        this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(224, 45);
        trackBar1.Maximum = 255;
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.trackBar2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();

        // TextBox for TrackBar.Value update.
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(240, 800);
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 20);

        // Set up how the form should be displayed and add the controls to the form.
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(296, 62);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[]
        {
            this.textBox1, this.trackBar1
        });
        this.Text = "TrackBar Example";

        // Set up the TrackBar.
        this.trackBar2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 100);
        this.trackBar2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(224, 45);
        trackBar2.Maximum = 255;
    }
}
```

It is running perfectly fine when i use trackbar1, when i define trackbar1 & trackbar2, i only see trackbar1 and not trackbar2. The code is giving no errors

note:This isn't the entire code, just a code snippet

Comment: good question. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enlarge your form a little more and change the:

```
   this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.textBox1, this.trackBar1 });
```

to

```
 this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.textBox2, this.trackBar2 });
```

In the trackBar2.

Also to see the TextBox2 you need to change the

```
this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(240, 800);
```

to

```
this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(240, 100);
```

Regards